# PyQt- get the coordinates of QGridLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I am using the Qt designer to create the GUI, and there is a QGridLayout object in it. I want to know the coordinates of the left top corner of the object.

The following code is in the .py file which converted from the .ui file.

```
self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 130, 731, 571))
self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
```

I can see that the left top position of the gridlayout is indeed (200,130) in my GUI window, if I click on it and print the event.pos(). the problem is that when I call:

```
self.gridLayout.geometry()
```

it returns "PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 731, 571)", so the width and height are wright, but the x and y position are not. How do I get the left top position of the QGridLayout object?

Comment: what does self.widget.geometry() return ?

Comment: Geometries are always relative to their parent. The top left corner of the layout is at `0, 0` meaning that it's in the top left corner of the widget, so the top left corner of the layout is actually the `self.widget.pos()`. But be aware that that too will be in coordinates relative to the parent. Note that it seems that you're adding that widget without a proper layout manager for the parent, while you should set the layout for the top level window instead (see [using layouts in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)). Besides, why do you need to know the layout coordinates?